# Print text between two strings on the same line

Tags: bash, sed, line, extract

I've been searching for a ling time, and have not been able to find a working answer for my problem.

I have a line from an HTML file extracted with `sed '162!d' skinlist.html`, which contains the text

`<a href="/skin/dwarf-red-beard-734/" title="Dwarf Red Beard">`.

I want to extract the text `Dwarf Red Beard`, but that text is modular (can be changed), so I would like to extract the text between `title="` and `"`.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==162 {print $4}' FS='"' skinlist.html
```

- set field separator to `"`
- print only line 162
- print field 4

Answer (score 1):

Solution in sed

```
sed -n '162 s/^.*title="\(.*\)".*$/\1/p' skinlist.html
```

Extracts line `162` in `skinlist.html` and captures the `title` attributes contents in`\1`.

Answer (score 0):

The shell's variable expansion syntax allows you to trim prefixes and suffixes from a string:

```
line="$(sed '162!d' skinlist.html)"   # extract the relevant line from the file
temp="${line#* title=\"}"    # remove from the beginning through the first match of ' title="'
if [ "$temp" = "$line" ]; then
    echo "title not found in '$line'" >&2
else
    title="${temp%%\"*}"   # remote from the first '"' through the end
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through another `sed` or add expressions to that `sed` like `-e 's/.*title="//g' -e 's/">.*$//g'`

Answer (score 0):

also sed

```
sed -n '162 s/.*"\([a-zA-Z ]*\)"./\1/p' skinlist.html
```